# How do I calculate the degree between the x=0 line and the line from the (0, 0) to the point (j, i)?

Tags: c

I have to return the angle in degrees and it should be in the range between 0 and 360 (inclusively). I have to use the functions in the math.h library, acos(), asin(), and atan(). In my instructions it says that depending on the quadrant that the point is in, the computation may be different.

Note: I will be using this function to draw an image later on, so I was thinking that the reason they say point (j, i) is because they are referring to the number of rows and columns, respectively. But I'm a little confused on how they are plotting the points. Is it the way you would plot on a coordinate plane in math? (j being the x coordinate and i being a y coordinate)

I've attempted a solution, but I got a little confused by the idea that depending on the quadrants, the computations would be different. I was thinking that I could use acos() for all four quadrants if I found the distance from the origin to the point (j, i) and if I just used the adjacent side which would just be the j coordinate. (If j is equivalent to the x coordinate when plotting the points)

```
float getAngle(int i, int j) {
   float distance, result, radians, degrees;

   distance = sqrt((j * j) + (i * i));

   if (j > 0 && i > 0) {
      result = cos(distance/j) * (1.0);
      radians = acos(result);
      degrees = radians * (180/3.14);
   }
}
```

Thank you in advance to everyone who posts advice up! I really appreciate it!

Comment: How about `M_PI / 2 - atan2(i, j)`? Also, if j <= 0 or i <= 0, you don't return anything from the function, whereas it's supposed to return a `float`. That's wrong - compile your code with all warnings enabled and **pay attention to warnings.**

Comment: Use `atan2(dy, dx)` to get the angle in radians in the correct quadrant from the line y=0 (where `dy` is ∆y and `dx` is ∆x). You need to sort out how to adjust it for the angle from the line x=0.  Convert to degrees by multiplying by 180 / π.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! But what if I can't use atan2()? Is there a way to do it without that function?

Comment: Check which quadrant the result will lie in (including boundary conditions like `x==0`, then divide, pass the quotient to atan, and do a bit of postprocessing based on the case you determined in the first step.

Comment: Google for `atan approximation` or `arctan approximation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265358979323

#if 0
double getAngle(int x, int y) {
    //angle(degree) from (0, 0) to (x, y) by acos
    double distance, cos_v, radians, degrees;

    distance = sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
    cos_v = x / distance;
    radians = acos(cos_v);
    if(y<0)
        radians=2.0*PI-radians;
    degrees = radians * (180.0/PI);
}
#else
double getAngle(int x, int y) {
    //angle(degree) from (0, 0) to (x, y) by atan2
    //(x ==0 && y==0) is error
    double radians, degrees;

    radians = atan2(y, x);
    if(radians<0)
        radians += 2.0*PI;
    degrees = radians * (180.0/PI);
}
#endif

int main(void){
    int data[][2] = {
        //(x, y)
        { 1, 0}, { 1,  1}, {0,  1}, {-1,  1},
        {-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {0, -1}, { 1, -1}
    };
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<8;++i)
        printf("%g\n", getAngle(data[i][0], data[i][1]));
    return 0;
}
```